# Reference to bpy.context.selected_objects does not reference updated selection list

Tags: python

Assume I have a scene with an object called 'Cube' and another one called 'Torus'. 'Cube' is selected to begin with. Now I execute the following lines of code:

```
import bpy

# reference to selected objects list
selected_objs = bpy.context.selected_objects

# select 'Torus' object
bpy.data.objects['Torus'].select_set(True)

print(bpy.context.selected_objects)
print(selected_objs)
```

```
OUTPUT:
[bpy.data.objects['Torus'], bpy.data.objects['Cube']]
[bpy.data.objects['Cube']]
```

While `bpy.context.selected_objects` obviously contains the updated selection, `selected_objs` only contains the initial selection, the 'Cube' but not the 'Torus'.

I would expect that `selected_objs` would contain the updated selection too, but it does not.

Why?

Comment: Why the expectation? The selected objects context property `context.selected_objects` is not a reference to some static  list, it is rather a new "snapshot copy" list returned  each time the prop is accessed. eg akin to a property def that returns  `[o for o in context.scene.objects if o.select_get()]`

Comment: OK. Where could I have found an answer to this question by myself?

Comment: Question answers itself somewhat.  `context.selected_objects is context.selected_objects` will be true if it refs the same list.